# How do I import many variables at once in javascript in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have a javascript module `first_file.js`:

```
var first = "first",
    second = "second",
    third = "third";

module.exports = {first, second, third};
```

How do I import these into another file in one line? The following only imports `third`:

```
var first, second, third = require('./path/to/first_file.js');
```

Comment: Looks like you only assigned it to the third variable. Why not use an object instead?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're exporting an object with those properties. You can get them either using the object directly:

```
var obj = require('./path/to/first_file.js');
obj.first;
obj.second;
obj.third;
```

Or using destructuring:

```
var { first, second, third } = require('./path/to/first_file.js');
```

As of version 4.1.1, Node.js does not yet support destructuring out of the box.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that destructuring isn't supported in Node yet (by default).

Comment: So what should we do for it to support it?

Comment: @samuelnihoul Node 4 is waaay out of date. Any modern version of Node supports destructuring

Answer (score 7):

In ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) you can use object destructuring:

```
const { first, second, third } = require('./path/to/first_file.js');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store them in an array:

```
module.exports = [first, second, third];
```

Comment: How is that better than an object?

Comment: @FelixKling it depends on the problem. "first, second, third" imply homogeneity and since the names don't have any information other than, well, the index, an array may be better.

Comment: @djechlin: that doesn't make a big difference regarding the issue though (how to import those values).

Comment: @FelixKling I guess I'm not sure I see your point. Would an object be better? If there's no difference then why did you ask how it's better than an object?

Comment: I assumed the problem needed a solution in ES5. The attributes would have to be named if an object was used.

Comment: @djechlin: The question is how to import multiple values. This answer suggests to use an array instead of an object. I don't see how that answers the question (that's basically what my comment implied).

Comment: @FelixKling the question hadn't even figured out how to do it with anything. It writes `{first, second, third}` which I *believe* executes a block of code running the statement `first, second, third`, by way of the comma operator, it actually looks like the easiest fix to OP's code is to turn the incorrectly written object to a correctly written array.

Comment: @djechlin: `{first, second, third}` is *short object notation* and is equivalent to `{first: first, second: second, third: third}`. It is valid code, hence my confusion about the array. The issue is with importing the value, not exporting it.

Comment: @FelixKling didn't know about that feature. you're right then.